# Common term for "present value" and "future value"

Tags: finance

In the past, I have always used the term "present value" for the value of a payment made at some point in time $t$ from the perspective of some other valuation point in time $T$. I did not distinguish the cases $t < T$ and $t > T$, as these cases are the same mathematically (and economically). E.g., if the interest rate is constant over time, one has
$$\text{present value} = \text{payment} \cdot (1+\text{interest rate})^{T-t},$$
and this equation is meaningful both for $t < T$ and for $t>T$.

Now a colleague of mine pointed out that the term "present value" is used only if $T < t$. Otherwise, the result of the above equation is called "future value". Probably, he is right (for instance, according to Wikipedia).

Now, is there any common term for the result of the above equation that I can use if I want to catch both cases?

Comment: I flagged off-topic because I think this is less relevant to math than economics or what ever (I am really unfamiliar with those areas) since these terminologies are not math concepts.

Comment: This is financial mathematics.

Comment: Instead of present value use value of money and yes your collegue is right and secondly when T is less then t Interest rate is k own as discount rate

Comment: **time** value of money